# Spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am having code from youtube tutorial, and i can not figure out why do we need parentheses(commented line), and if anyone can explain in simple way this code... thanks

```
  const [{count, count2}, setCount] = useState({count: 10, count2: 20})

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={ () => 
        setCount(
          currentState => (//can not understand
            {...currentState, count: currentState.count+1}
          )
        )}>+</button>
      <h5>Count 1: {count}</h5>
      <h5>Count2: {count2}</h5>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the spread operator.

The `=>` of an arrow function can be followed by either:

- An expression
- A block

Since, in JavaScript, a `{` can start a block or an object initializer (which depends on context), anywhere you *could* put a block but *want* an object initializer you need to add wrap it in `()` so that the `{` is treated as the start of an expression.

Comment: This answer's taught me how to explain a problem right and concise ^^

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need parentheses

I guess because without them `()`, it **won't work**, throws the error even on compile time.

```
setCount(
  currentState => (//can not understand
    {...currentState, count: currentState.count+1}
  )
)
```

`setCount` is a [setState hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). It has 2 syntax:

1. `setCount( newStateOfCount )` (set state with direct value)
2. `setCount( oldCount => newCount )` (set state using a callback)

And yours is the second one. With the callback return an object, you have 2 options:

```
currentState => {
  return {
    ...currentState, 
    count: currentState.count+1
  }
}
```

which is more verbose than

```
currentState => ({
  ...currentState, 
  count: currentState.count+1
})
```

So in the tutorial he used the second syntax, because it's **more concise**.

Without the parentheses it doesn't work:

```
currentState => {
  ...currentState, 
  count: currentState.count+1
}
```

Because the parser will understand that `{` is the begin of a `function body`, rather than `an object`, **it won't be able to figure it out, without you explicitly give it the `()`**

Comment: so basically ( ) is something let's say escape character?

Comment: @Edy Yes, I think roughly the idea is that. *Some character* is special in some context, so we need 1 extra "escape character" to make the language understand it correctly *(for that context)*.